# SBT: Ampersand (&) is not a member of sbt.io.FileFilter

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to create a beginner Scala application using SBT with the following build.sbt

```
name := "Jala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" && "scalatest" & "2.2.6" & "test"
```

And I receive the error:

```
Error while importing sbt project:

[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\janac\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\source\Jala\project
C:\source\Jala\build.sbt:7: error: value & is not a member of sbt.io.FileFilter
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" && "scalatest" & "2.2.6" & "test"
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

I don't understand why the error message suggests that "&" is not a valid member...

Comment: It should be should be percent sign `%`, not ampersand `&`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin that solved my error, but I now get `Expression type Def.Setting[Seq[ModuleID]] must conform to DslEntry in sbt file`

Comment: I'm not sure what that new error means. I'd suggest to update your question with the new [mcve] and a more complete quote of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `&` use `%` and append a `Seq` like this:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "2.2.6")
```

Using a `Seq` is handy for appending more dependencies if you need in the near future.